# Unable to use Sass on macOS Catalina

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, homebrew, macos-catalina

Since upgrading to Catalina I'm not being able to use Ruby Sass. I tried installing Node Sass but I keep getting this message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/luiscarlospandocarrera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/libruby.2.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/luiscarlospando/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/bin/ruby
```

I tried uninstalling Ruby Sass, reinstalling it and I just keep getting this message.

What would I need to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Ruby problem, so maybe reinstall Ruby, or possibly bump to a newer version to see if that side-steps the issue. 2.7.0 is out and worth a shot. From time to time an OS upgrade will pull a library your locally built Ruby depends on, so you need to rebuild Ruby to link to the new, updated libraries.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby SASS is EOL (26 March 2019) - https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass and you should try to find other ways to "compile" your SASS files.

I uses sassc with PHPStorm as a runner for the themes that uses SASS.

Easiest way to install is by using homebrew:

`brew install sassc`

You should also consider using https://github.com/sass/dart-sass

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by installing the latest version of Ruby as suggested by [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60825302/2197860) by using Ruby Version Manager (rvm).

To do it I did the following steps:

1. Installed the latest version of rvm:
   `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` and then I had to restart the terminal.
2. Installed the latest version of Ruby:
   `rvm install ruby-2.7.0`
3. I did set `v2.7.0` as the version of Ruby I wanted to use:
   `rvm --default use ruby-2.7.0`

I hope this helps!